# Is it possible to create half page masters in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am creating an attendee guide for a meeting. Each page has a company description on the top half and a second company at the bottom half. The companies need to be listed alphabetically, however companies will add and drop as the guide is being created. Is there a way to create a master for the top half, and a master for the bottom half, so that I can move companies around by the half page without having to reorganize the entire guide?

see attached example[image]

Comment: Hi Jackie, welcome to GD.SE! Master pages encompasses the whole page, no matter how big the page size is. Does your background layout change depending on what company is on that page? What do you mean by "Guide"? I would also look into doing a Data Merge within InDesign, that could save you a lot of time. Or you could do this with XML but that might be more difficult to learn.

Comment: Try giving this a go:
https://indesignsecrets.com/vertical-master-page-spreads.php#

Comment: I don't fully understand the question (or workflow). If there are 10 companies and each company has it's own information, which appears a maximum of *once* in the guide -- what use are master pages at all other than a master for the primary page header? Master pages are designed for *repetitive* content. Unless the companies have multiple "info" boxes, there's no benefit to master pages here. It sounds like *layers* and *groups* may help more than master pages.

Comment: Where are you getting the info about the companies from? Are they in a predictably structured format? It sounds like this would be a good candidate for storing the data in an XML file and import that. Use threaded frames and the “Start paragraph” options cleverly and you should be able to do this fairly easily. You can then move individual companies around freely as well as deleting them and adding new ones by importing from XML again.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy to achieve by using **"Rotate the spread view"** feature.
Apply rotation to master pages and to all pages.

Go Page panel menu > Page attributes > Rotate Spread view > 90° CW, 90° CCW, 180°, or cancel. (I believe this can vary depending on your INDD version).

Complete documentation here: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/pages-spreads-1.html#rotate_the_spread_view

See example below:

[image: INDD rotate spreads]

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to deal with this, neither ideal:

1. Create a master page with 2 companies. You have to update everything twice if you change the master, but twice is better than for every company.
2. Create a separate document at half page size with the companies. When you've got them in, export that to a pdf and place that pdf into your full page indesign document. You can go back to the half page document and overwrite the pdf with any changes.